# Can you Contingency a spell from a Ring of Spell Storing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

The [*contingency*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency) spell requires that you "can cast" the contingent spell (of fifth level or lower).

A [Ring of Spell Storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing) lets you store up to a single 5th-level spell by any caster (for example, a [*death ward*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/death-ward) cast by a friendly cleric) and later be able to cast it yourself (using the initial caster's modifier/DC if applicable) even if it's not normally on your list.

If you have a spell that you don't normally know inside your Ring of Spell Storing, can you then choose it as the contingent spell for *contingency*?

Comment: Very related: [Can Contingency be used with a spell cast from an Ioun Stone?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124689)

Comment: Ahh, good catch. It even talks about the Ring in there.

Comment: This post was discussed on Meta [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8184/should-this-question-actually-be-marked-as-duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

Contingency requires the caster, "you" in the description, to expend spell slots for both spells at the time of casting *contingency*.

> You cast that spell--called the contingent spell--as part of casting contingency, expending spell slots for both...

The spell slots for the spell in the ring were either expended previously, or by a different caster.

Comment: As a certain orange man would say : SAD !

Comment: I concur that it seems nit picky, but I then considered how I would potentially abuse contingency and compared that to the situations where this is needed or improves the story.